# crontab : yesterday's date not showing up

Tags: date, cron

I need a cron job to work on a file named like this:

```
20160307_20160308_xxx_yyy.csv
(yesterday_today_xxx_yyy.csv)
```

And my cron job looks like this:

```
53 11 * * * /path/to/python /path/to/python/script /path/to/file/$(date -d "yesterday" +"\%Y\%m\%d")_$(date +"\%Y\%m\%d")_xxx_yyy.csv >> /path/to/logfile/cron.log 2>&1
```

Today's date is getting calculated properly but I am unable to get yesterday's date working. The error is:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tmp/_20160308_xxx_yyy.csv'
```

Please help!

Comment: Did you forget to use `-d "yesterday"` on the second call of `date`?

Comment: I am using `-d "yesterday"` on the first call. Please look at the format of my file. It's yesterday_today_xxx_yyy.csv

Comment: Oops, sorry. Is it different if you remove the space between `-d` and  `"yesterday"`? Are the backslashes required? (it works without backslashes on my Ubuntu)

Comment: Do you mean -d=yesterday or -d="yesterday" ? I tried both of them and it isn't working. Backslashes are required in my case, refer first comment in the chosen answer in [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8584/using-the-system-date-time-in-a-cron-script) thread.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to my own question.

I needed to use this to get yesterday's date:

```
53 11 * * * /path/to/python /path/to/python/script /path/to/file/$(date -v-1d +"\%Y\%m\%d")_$(date +"\%Y\%m\%d")_xxx_yyy.csv >> /path/to/logfile/cron.log 2>&1
```

Hope it helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

This version worked for me. Maybe it can be helpful for someone:

```
53 11 * * * /path/to/python /path/to/python/script /path/to/file/$(date --date '-1 day' +"\%Y\%m\%d")_$(date +"\%Y\%m\%d")_xxx_yyy.csv >> /path/to/logfile/cron.log 2>&1
```